# I have sections which have a feelings property which is an array of objects. How to filter all feelings which are selected from all sections in array?

Tags: javascript

I have the following JSON structure:

```
const sections = [
    {
        title: "section one",
        expanded: false,
        feelings: [
            {
                title: "Joyful",
                selected: true,
            },
            {
                title: "Happy",
                selected: false,
            },
            {
                title: "Ecstatic",
                selected: true,
            },
        ]
    },
    {
        title: "section two",
        expanded: false,
        feelings: [
            {
                title: "Angry",
                selected: true,
            },
            {
                title: "Mad",
                selected: false,
            },
        ]
    },
]
```

I want to filter all feelings that are selected in an array of their own disregarding their section. So the expected outcome should look like this:

```
[
    {
      "title": "Joyful",
      "selected": true
    },
    {
      "title": "Ecstatic",
      "selected": true
    },
    {
      "title": "Angry",
      "selected": true
    }
]
```

I tried the following:

```
const selectedFeelings = feelings.map((feeling) => {
    return feeling.sectionFeelings.filter((sectionFeeling) => {
        return sectionFeeling.selected === true;
    });
});
```

But this returns them in separate arrays:

```
[
  [
    {
      "title": "Joyful",
      "selected": true
    },
    {
      "title": "Ecstatic",
      "selected": true
    }
  ],
  [
    {
      "title": "Angry",
      "selected": true
    },
  ],
]
```

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flatMap

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [`Array.flatMap()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flatMap) along with [`Array.filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) to return the desired result:

```js
const sections = [ { title: "section one", expanded: false, feelings: [ { title: "Joyful", selected: true, }, { title: "Happy", selected: false, }, { title: "Ecstatic", selected: true, }, ] }, { title: "section two", expanded: false, feelings: [ { title: "Angry", selected: true, }, { title: "Mad", selected: false, }, ] }, ]

const selectedFeelings = sections.flatMap((section) => {
    return section.feelings.filter(({ selected }) => selected);
});

console.log(selectedFeelings)
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; }
```

You could also use [`Array.reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) to get the same result:

```js
const sections = [ { title: "section one", expanded: false, feelings: [ { title: "Joyful", selected: true, }, { title: "Happy", selected: false, }, { title: "Ecstatic", selected: true, }, ] }, { title: "section two", expanded: false, feelings: [ { title: "Angry", selected: true, }, { title: "Mad", selected: false, }, ] }, ]

const selectedFeelings = sections.reduce((acc, {feelings}) => {
    return [...acc, ...feelings.filter(({ selected }) => selected)];
}, []);

console.log(selectedFeelings)
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can flatten the returned array once you filter it

```
const selectedFeelings = feelings.map((feeling) => {
    return feeling.sectionFeelings.filter((sectionFeeling) => {
        return sectionFeeling.selected === true;
    });
}).flat(1);
```

Answer (score 0):

this is using ES6

```js
const sections = [
  {
    title: "section one",
    expanded: false,
    feelings: [
      {
        title: "Joyful",
        selected: true,
      },
      {
        title: "Happy",
        selected: false,
      },
      {
        title: "Ecstatic",
        selected: true,
      },
    ]
  },
  {
    title: "section two",
    expanded: false,
    feelings: [
      {
        title: "Angry",
        selected: true,
      },
      {
        title: "Mad",
        selected: false,
      },
    ]
  },
];

const newArr = sections.map(({ feelings, ...rest }) => {
  return rest;
});

console.log(newArr);
```